# Show that $\int_{S^{n-1}}(\Delta _{S}f) gd\sigma=\int_{S^{n-1}}f( \Delta _{S}g)d\sigma$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Elias M. Stein said that by an application of Green's theorem the following equality holds

$\int_{S^{n-1}}(\Delta _{S}f) gd\sigma=\int_{S^{n-1}}f( \Delta _{S}g)d\sigma$

where $\Delta _{S}$ is a spherical laplacian.

I don't know how to use the Green's theorem because both sides have the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

The Laplacian is a second-order operator, so you'll apply Green's theorem twice. Since the sphere doesn't have boundary and the Laplacian is $\operatorname{div}\nabla,$

$$\int (\Delta f)g\ d\sigma = -\int \langle \nabla f,\nabla g\rangle\ d\sigma = \int f(\Delta g)\ d\sigma.$$

(Green's theorem is basically integrating by parts.)

Wikipedia calls this "[Green's first identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities)." What I'm quoting is the $n$-dimensional analogue. Formally, the intuition is that you integrate by parts in each coordinate and since the boundary is empty, the boundary terms vanish:
$$ \int f\Delta g = \int f\sum \partial_i^2g = \sum \int f\partial_i^2 g = -\sum\int \partial_if\partial_ig=-\int \langle\nabla f,\nabla g\rangle. $$

If you're comfortable with Stokes' theorem, this is a [consequence of the product rule](https://www.math.okstate.edu/~binegar/5233-S96/5233-l21.pdf) for the divergence:
$$ 0 = \int_{\partial S} f\nabla g\cdot nd\sigma =\int_S \nabla \cdot (f\nabla g)d\sigma=\int_S\langle \nabla f,\nabla g\rangle +f\Delta g\ d\sigma $$